# How can i store a vector-list as a global variable?

Tags: c++, class, struct, stdvector

I am creating a tree that consists of branches. For the purpose of my work, I need to keep track of the branches, and In order to do that, I want to store them in a vector-list. I store the vector-list as a global variable in this file, as I want to use it in both the constructor and the function shown in the code snippet below.

The tricky part here is that I get an error message (running in Visual Studio 2013) that as far as I can tell has something to do with the iterator not doing its job properly. The error message appears whenever i call branchList.push_back(root) and branchList.resize(). branchList.size() does NOT result in an error.

So my question is: What am I missing / not understanding to make this work? If i were to place vector branchList; in the beginning of the constructor, everything works as intended. This however does not help me, since I need to also use it in other functions later on.

Relevant code snippets from the files I am using.

skeletonBuilder.h:

```
class TreeSkeleton {

public:
    TreeSkeleton();
    void growTree();
};
```

skeletonBuilder.cpp:

```
#include "skeletonBuilder.h"
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>


typedef struct branch {
    branch *parent;
    vec3 position;
    vec3 direction;
} branch;

//used by constructor + "treeGrow" function
std::vector<branch> branchList = {};

TreeSkeleton::TreeSkeleton() {
    //instantiate the tree root as a starting position.
    branch root;
    root.parent = NULL;
    root.position = vec3(0, 0, 0);
    root.direction = vec3(0, 1, 0); 

    branchList.size(); //works fine
    branchList.resize(100); //Crashes here
    branchList.push_back(root); //Crashes here
}

TreeSkeleton::growTree() {
    //pushing more branches to branchList
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "skeletonBuilder.h"

TreeSkeleton tree;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    return 0;
}
```

The error message I am getting:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00507077 in OpenGL_project_Debug.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x40EAAAB4.
```

The error message takes me to the following code snippet in a file called "vector":

```
 #if _VECTOR_ORPHAN_RANGE
void _Orphan_range(pointer _First, pointer _Last) const
    {   // orphan iterators within specified (inclusive) range
    _Lockit _Lock(_LOCK_DEBUG);
    const_iterator **_Pnext = (const_iterator **)this->_Getpfirst();
    if (_Pnext != 0)
        while (*_Pnext != 0) //<----------------This is the row that it gets stuck on
            if ((*_Pnext)->_Ptr < _First || _Last < (*_Pnext)->_Ptr)
                _Pnext = (const_iterator **)(*_Pnext)->_Getpnext();
            else
                {   // orphan the iterator
                (*_Pnext)->_Clrcont();
                *_Pnext = *(const_iterator **)(*_Pnext)->_Getpnext();
                }
    }
```

Comment: Please copy paste the *exact* error message you are getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initialization order of global objects is not guaranteed between implementation files. There is no way to know rather the globals of `main.cpp` or `skeletonBuilder.cpp` will be initialized first. In your case, `TreeSkeleton tree` is initialized before `std::vector<branch> branchList` which leads to your problem. The constructor of `TreeSkeleton` must use the uninitialized `branchList` which is undefined behavior. The solution is to place your globals in such a way that the order *is* guaranteed.

One solution is to make `branchList` a local static variable. These variables are guaranteed to be initialized when first encountered.

For example :

```
class TreeSkeleton {

public:
    TreeSkeleton();
    void growTree();

private:
    static std::vector<branch> & getBranches();
};

std::vector<branch> & TreeSkeleton::getBranches()
{
    // branchList is initialized the first time this line is encountered
    static std::vector<branch> branchList;
    return branchList;
}

TreeSkeleton::TreeSkeleton() 
{
    //instantiate the tree root as a starting position.
    branch root;
    root.parent = NULL;
    root.position = vec3(0, 0, 0);
    root.direction = vec3(0, 1, 0);

    auto & branchList = getBranches();
    branchList.size();
    branchList.push_back(root); // Should be fine now
}
```

Comment: Even better would be to eliminate globals entirely. I see no good reason these variables need to be global, rather than the vector being contained within the tree (either as a member or as a static if its to be shared between all trees) and the tree being declared inside the main function...

Comment: Okay, I understand what you're saying and will try to use the functions you wrote. However, one issue is that the struct branch has been implemented in the .cpp file, meaning that the "static std::vector<branch> ..." does not know what "branch" is.

Comment: If you must, you can change the static member function to a free-function in the implementation file.

Comment: Oh, Im sorry. I must've misunderstood your example. Did you mean to include all of the above code in a single .cpp/.h file?

Comment: @VictorO. No, that's not what I meant to suggest. My initial suggestion was to add a single private static method to `TreeSkeleton` that would return the static vector. This implied adding a declaration for that method in the header file and an implementation in the cpp file (just like any other member method). However, since you're concerned that the definition of `branch`  is not available in the header, I propose an alternative where instead of defining a new static method you could simply define an equivalent free function strictly in the .cpp file. I hope that clears thing up for you.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks for all the explanations. I took a break, came back and had a fresh look at your answers, and decided to put the struct in a separate header file since I plan to be using the branch struct in several different files in the future. Your functions definitely were of help! Marking this as the right answer.